# How to rewrite numerous URL's at once?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a series of price lists from various manufacturers (spat out from a database). They are limited to 100 rows per page, ie:

```
www.domain.com/products/price-lists/company1.php?page=2
www.domain.com/products/price-lists/company2.php?page=10
```

which i want to rewrite to:

```
www.domain.com/products/price-lists/company1/page/2
www.domain.com/products/price-lists/company2/page/10
```

I have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^products/price-lists/company1/page/([0-9]+)/?$ products/price-lists/company1.php?page=$1 [NC,L] 
RewriteRule ^products/price-lists/company2/page/([0-9]+)/?$ products/price-lists/company2.php?page=$1 [NC,L]
```

First of all, this throws a 404 if i try to go to /products/price-lists/company1/page/2 (it works if i remove /page/) and second, i was wondering if i could combine them into one rule anyway:

```
(company1|company2[0-9]+)/?
```

Thanks for any help (this is my first mod_rewrite attempt!)

Comment: Do you mean you want a single rule that will handle the different permutations of the full URL?

Comment: @Oded - Yes. So i didnt need one Rewrite rule per manufacturer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^products/price-lists/([a-z0-9_\-]+)(/page)?/?$ products/price-lists/$1.php?page=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^products/price-lists/([a-z0-9_\-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ products/price-lists/$1.php?page=$2 [NC,L]
```

The first rule will check if a page is there or not without a number and go to page 1. The `([a-z0-9_\-]+)` will be use to put the company, so if you put:

```
http://www.domain.com/products/price-lists/stackoverflow/page/2
```

the `/products/price-lists/stackoverflow.php` will open using `$_GET['page'] = 2`

Comment: Thank you. Based on your answer I ended up with:

`RewriteRule ^price-lists/([a-z0-9-]+)/page/?$ price-lists/$1.php?page=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^price-lists/([a-z0-9-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ price-lists/$1.php?page=$2 [NC,L]`

By any chance could you explain the: `([a-z0-9_\-]+)(/page)?/` (i didnt understand it so changed it to what you see above, which seems to work

Comment: You welcome. The ([a....]) check for any letters, numbers, underscore and dash and that goes in the $1. The other is optional because of the ?   So at the end you can look for page or page/ or nothing

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the part of the url is the same as the filename of the php file (without the `.php`). Use the following to correct.

`options -multiviews`